# How to run search as user types in messaging system

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a messaging system, and pretty much everything is done except this part.

This is the form I have:

```
<%= form_for :message, url: messages_path(7) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :message, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Write a message...' %>
    <div class="clearfix"><%= f.submit 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right' %></div>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, this form will send a message to user, which has user id 7. So, creating message also works but some how I should be searching through users in database as user types, and after user selected, I should be dynamically changing value here with the id chosen by user. `messages_path(7)` This is how facebook, or gmail does. I guess there is no other way. I have no idea how to do this.

As I said, everything is done, I just need to run search through users name as sender type recipient name, and user selected recipient, I gotta replace id dynamically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use AJAX to get your users from the database.
Than you can easliy modify the id you are posting to on the client side

I wrote something that might get you on the right track :)

```
function getUsers () {
    $.getJSON('localhost/{your-file-to-user-query}',{
    headers: {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json",
    async: false
    }).success(function(data) {
        var id, name, html;
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if(data !== "")
        {
            //Parse all user data and put them in a list
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                id    = data[i].id;
                name  = data[i].name;
                html += '<div onclick = "selectUser(' + id + ')" class = "user-block">'+
                        '<p>' + name + '</p>'+
                        '</div>';
            }
        $('{Some_container_to_put_this_list_in}').html(html);

         }
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}

function selectUser (id) {
    //Don't know alot about RoR but you need to add an id to your form so you can select it easily
    //And than you replace the current id with the id that came from the list item you clicked on 
    $('form').attr('url',messages_path(id))
}
```